# detecting a float with regex in JavaScript is not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to detect if my number (mynum) is a float or not. I consider 12.0 or 1.0 a float as well. I consider 12 or 1 not to be a float.

I really tried everything, but every regex gives me : true

```
   const myreg = /^-?\d+(?:[.,]\d*?)?$/;
   console.log('my test:', mynum, ' ', myreg.test(mynum));
```

It gives me true to 12, gives me true to 12.1, everything

I tried other regex expressions as well, they all give me true.

I'm out of ideas because all I see is true.

Comment: Drop the last `?`. That makes the decimal part optional.

Comment: tested with number and string as well, everywhere : true, true, ture

Comment: Botje - yesss ! Dropped the last "?" and it started working ! Thank youuu !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its always true because you have decimal point and digits after it as optional, also it would match invalid numbers that ends with a decimal point.

Try this:

```js
const myreg = /^-?\d+[.,]\d+$/;
 for(let i = 0, n = [0, 2.0, "2.0", 2.1]; i < n.length; i++)
 {
   const mynum = n[i];
   console.log('my test:', mynum, ' ', myreg.test(mynum));
 }
```

Comment: as Botje commented, yes, there was a "?" sign that made the "." optional. It's working now, thank you very much